# how to filter data according to key words in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing an problem to retrieve data with respect to filter key words .I have message table like this

My **filter table**:-

```
+--+-------+-----------+---------+---------------+
|id|user_id|for_page_id|key_words|    message    |
+--+-------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| 1|     12|        2  |he,you   |You are awesome|
| 2|     12|        2  |the,book |this is good   |
+--+-------+-----------+---------+---------------+
```

I have a **string of key words** and i want to find the **corresponding message** for that key word.
I tried this:-

```
$string='he is good';
$keyWords=explode(' ',$string);
$query="SELECT * FROM `filter` WHERE `key_words` like '".$keyWords[0]."' or`key_words` like 
        '".$keyWords[1]."' or`key_words` like '".$keyWords[2]."'";
echo ($query);
```

The query look likes

```
SELECT * FROM `filter` WHERE `key_words` like 'he' or`key_words` like 'is' or`key_words` like 'good'
```

It gives output as

```
| 1|     12|        2  |he,you   |You are awesome|
| 2|     12|        2  |the,book |this is good   |
```

Accepted output is

```
| 1|     12|        2  |he,you   |You are awesome|
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I would better suggest to use little php code rather trying to do it only with MYSQL. Like in Mysql will compare that part of string and if it matches, it will return all content of the column. So the approach is wrong.

Comment: Okay then how can i do this by php code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope will help you

```
$string='he is good';
$keyWords=explode(' ',$string);
$searchQuery='';
foreach ($keyWords as $word) {
    $word = trim($word);
    if ($word) {
        $searchQuery = $searchQuery . "find_in_set('$word', trim(key_words)) > 0 or ";
    }
}
$searchQuery = chop($searchQuery, ' or ');
$query="SELECT * FROM filter WHERE ".$searchQuery;
echo ($query);
```

Query will be like

```
SELECT * FROM filter WHERE find_in_set('he', trim(key_words)) > 0 or find_in_set('is', trim(key_words)) > 0 or find_in_set('good', trim(key_words)) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The FIND_IN_SET() function is probably what you are looking for.

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
-> 2
```

It returns 0 if the string is not found in the list.

Here is a link to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.